# force jboss 6 to pickup a jar after deployment

Tags: java, deployment, jar, jboss6.x, ear-file

I have a webapp with a giant ear and it gets deployed.  Once it's deployed it's in the deployment directory and it's locked.

I want to be able to update the jars in this directory without having to restart/redeploy.  I've tried various forms of deployment (jboss-cli, console, filename.dodeploy) but nothing has worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your structure to replace class file.
Place ear in exploded format in Jboss_home\server\deploy.
In ear place class files directly.
So your final structure looks like
$JBOSS_HOME

--server

----$profile

------deploy

--------app.ear

----------com

------------a.class

----------app.war

----------META-INF

------------application.xml

Now you can replace the class file(a.class) directly inside app.ear.
Note: Method signature, member variable changes are not reflected.
Make sure your deployment scanner is on.
If you have IDE like eclipse u can also create link of class folder inside app.ear so that you dont have to copy the changed class file manually.

Comment: what do you mean by deployment scanner?  Also I already have a deployment with the exploded ear (with jar files)in a folder under deployments (remember this is jboss 6).  I deploy the file by using a filename <ear name>.deployed.  When I restart it picks up the changes but not while the server is running.  Are you sure this has worked for you for jboss6? seems like the structure you presented at the top is for jboss 5

Comment: I tried with JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final  Here is the link for deployment scanner https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/TurnDeploymentScannerDown

Comment: I have the scanner defined in my standalone.xml file: 

        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="true" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>

When I move new jars into the deployments folder, it basically deploys like a normal deploy process (as it does when the server starts) and doesn't 'hot deploy' which should be immediate.   :(

Comment: I tried with wildfly-8.2.0.Final with remote debugging On in eclipse it works. Try not to replace jar instead use link of eclipse generated class files in wildfly.